# .htaccess config not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, regex

Here is my current situation:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]

#the rule
RewriteRule ^post.php?id=([a-z0-9-]+)$ /post/$1.php


# how my url’s look like: http://localhost/post.php?id=article-slug-name

# how i want them to look like http://localhost/post/article-slug-name

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

As it says on the file

- How my url’s look like: http: //localhost/post.php?id=article-slug-name
- How i want them to look like http ://localhost/post/article-slug-name

I've been trying for days and searched all forums, just can't make it work... The file works because the enable-404-page command i include at the end works. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Rewrite Rules in a while but I believe the order is:

```
RewriteRule reg-exp-source destination
```

So your rule should look like

```
RewriteRule ^post/([a-z0-9-]+)$ post.php?id=$1
```

Also, I normally use the criteria `([^/\.]+)` in order to avoid picking up things after another slash, backslash, or dot.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! The code works. However, for some reason the page when going from the new links do not load my custom style sheet. In the inspector: Style sheet could not be loaded. localhost/post/css/style.css. I can't understand why it is loading that link... my html points to <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> – I think i need to exclude files that aren't posts, but i really don't know how. (.css, .png, etc)

Comment: @J.Gal your browser thinks that you are in the directory `/post/` so it searches for the resource `css/style.css` in `/post/css/style.css` whereas the true file is probably located at `/css/style.css`. I would recommend any of your links are absolute, rather than relative, to avoid this. So `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`.